# Broken foreign key constraint definition MySql

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

We were adding foreign key on a very large table, now beside it lasted really long seems like it did not finished properly, as constraint is not visible in table ddl. We tried to repeat adding but error was that such key already exist. Now if we try to remove that key error is that key is not present.

i checked information schema and found record for 'broken' foreign key that looks like this:

```
ID                 | FOR_NAME              | REF_NAME
test/fk_t_some_id   test/#sql-1069_69c3f2f  test/car
```

hot to handle this situation now? what would be the proper thing to do here as we cant add it again, or delete it? another name is an option, but how to clean up this thing?

Comment: You might want to add some code to your question, like how to you create your table, how is FK added, etc.